# Closest equivalent of "Don't get mad, get even" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, sentence-translation

I am looking for the closest equivalents of the following phrase in Latin:

> Don't get mad, get even.

Preferably not a word-by-word translation, but an 'established' phrase or proverb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of an established proverb, but if you want to convey the meaning "don't become angry, but [calmly] avenge yourself" you could translate **noli irasci, ulciscere** or (to keep the parallelism of the English phrase) **ne irascere, ulciscere**.